# How to make standard sample for NMR signal-to-noise ratio

Tags: nmr-spectroscopy

I want to make a sample for proton NMR signal-to-noise-ratio measurement. It is conventional to use 1% ethylbenzene in *d*-chloroform, as specified [here](https://www.drugfuture.com/Pharmacopoeia/usp38/data/v38332/usp38nf33s2_c761.html).

I have two questions:

1. What is meant exactly, by 1% ethylbenzene? In some places, I see the notation (v/v), which I take to mean 1% by volume. However, I am still not clear what this means. Does it mean that an amount of ethylbenzene should be used that would fill 1% of the final volume when the solvent is not present? Or does it mean to fill 99% of the final volume with the solvent and then add ethylbenzene until I reach the total volume? Or something else?
2. What is a good procedure for making such a solution? I imagine a volumetric flask would be useful, but should the solute be measured out by weight? Or using a pipette? I only need about 10 mL of the final solution.

Comment: 10 ml of final solution by 1% v/v should contain 0.1 ml Ethyl benzene.

Comment: My personal opinion is that it's better measure out the solute by weight, because common lab weight machines have more precision (4 decimal places i.e. 0.0001 g) than common pipettes (~0.1 mL)

Comment: Ask the manufacturer for a standard suitable for the experiment and spectral range in mind ([example](https://bruker-labscape.store/products/nmr-reference-standards-for-5mm-probes?variant=1017773490204)) or a befriended NMR group because eventually, these are flame sealed (no evaporation of the solvent across the cap). I saw [strychnine](http://triton.iqfr.csic.es/guide/tutorials/specdata/strychnine.html) in multiple places (equally to anticipate the time of recording necessary) to run a test according to ASTM E2977 and the [MNova](https://nmr.chem.ucsb.edu/protocols/SNR.html) program.

Comment: It is often much easier to buy these standards - most major chemical/NMR suppliers have them. Note also that the S/N standards are field dependent: a 1% EB standard is for lower fields (<300MHz by memory). Higher fields use 0.1%EB. The preparation of such standards follows the same protocols as for the preparation of any quantitative solution, but it is always easier to make them on a larger scale and only use the volume you need.

Comment: Thanks for these comments. I will use the tabulated density of ethylbenzene and a balance to fill 1% of the volume of a volumetric flask with ethylbenzene, then add solvent to the graduation mark.

Comment: For small quantities of a liquid, you may fill your volumetric flask to about four fifths with with your solvent "X".  Then record the mass difference of a small syringe a) filled with toluene, b) after disposing the toluene in "X" as the mass of toluene added.  Eventually fill the flask to the mark with solvent "X".  This allows you to work rapidly, because otherwise quite some of toluene may evaporate from the flask / a Pasteur pipette until the stem solution is prepared.

Comment: Toluene <—> Ethylbenzene. This sounds like a good idea, to measure the mass change of a small syringe rather than the mass change of the flask. I don’t understand why the standard is not specified by molarity. It would give the same result but one would not have to know the density of the solute.

Comment: Oh I see my error. You are spot on to object that toluene is not ethylbenzene.  The practice to put a small syringe (e.g., the about 1 mL) on a balance is a technique borrowed from determining manually water concentrations by Karl-Fischer, or organometallic / Grignard reagents against e.g., diphenyl acetic acid.  Of course you may reach out to machines for the former, or record a no-D NMR for the later (e.g., [this Hoye paper](https://doi.org/10.1021/ol049979+)) if you may record the spectrum by yourself.